# Retain NaN values after concatenating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df where I want to apply a function. How can I retain the NaN values even after concatenating two columns? I want to avoid `np.where` since the real function has more elif conditions

```
df  fruit   year price  vol  signifiance
0   apple   2010  1      5    NaN
1   apple   2011  2      4    NaN
2   apple   2012  3      3    NaN
3   NaN     2013  3      3    NaN
4   NaN     NaN   NaN    3    NaN
5   apple   2015  3      3   important
```

```
df = df.fillna('')
def func(row):
     if (pd.notna(row['year'])):
          return row['fruit']  + row['significance'] +row['price']+ '_test'
     else:
          return np.NaN
```

```
df['final'] = row.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Expected Output

```
df  fruit   year price  vol  significance   final 
0   apple   2010  1      5    NaN           apple1_test
1   apple   2011  2      4    NaN           apple2_test
2   apple   2012  3      3    NaN           apple3_test
3   NaN     2013  3      3    NaN           3_test
4   NaN     2014  NaN    3    NaN            NaN
5   apple   2015  3      3   important   appleimportant3_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.fillna('')
def func(row):
     a = f"{row['fruit']}{row['significance']}{row['price']}"
     if a:
         return a + '_test'
     return np.NaN
```

Comment: Unsupported operand type +: for float and str

Comment: This works but I lose the NaN that were showing across the whole dataframe because of the fillna

Comment: make a copy of the df before hand... copy_df = df.copy(); copy_df = copy_df.fillna(''); df['final']=df_copy.apply(func)

Answer (score 1):

First remove `df = df.fillna('')` and then use your solution with added `elif` for test if missing values in both columns:

```
def func(row):
     if (pd.notna(row['fruit'])) & (pd.notna(row['signifiance'])):
          return row['fruit'] +'_' + row['signifiance']
     elif (pd.isna(row['fruit'])) & (pd.isna(row['signifiance'])):
          return 'apple'
     else:
           return row['fruit']

df['final'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print (df)
   df  fruit  year  price  vol signifiance            final
0   0  apple  2010      1    5         NaN            apple
1   1  apple  2011      2    4         NaN            apple
2   2  apple  2012      3    3         NaN            apple
3   3  apple  2013      3    3         NaN            apple
4   4    NaN  2014      3    3         NaN            apple
5   5  apple  2015      3    3   important  apple_important
```

Comment: Sorry updated the question, for the final time, I promise. I tried to do ```df['fruit'].fillna('')``` in the forloop too but then I got the error: str object has no attribute 'fill'na'

Comment: @asd It means `df` was overwritten som string like `df = 'a'`